# Apache Geronimo Console - Session Overview

Tags: session, geronimo

The Apache Tomcat manager app provides a nice session overview where I can see all active sessions for each web application:

[image: Apache Tomcat Session Administration]

But for Apache Geronimo I miss such a feature. I'm not sure if it just doesn't exist or if I haven't found it yet.

So does Apache Geronimo provide a similar feature and if yes where can I find it?